# insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint "" and duplicate foreign keys

Tags: sql, pgadmin

ERROR:  insert or update on table "flight" violates foreign key constraint "flight_flight_num_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (flight_num)=(100) is not present in table "booked_on".

```
drop table if exists CUSTOMER;
drop table if exists BOOKED_ON;
drop table if exists PLANE_TYPE;
drop table if exists EMPLOYEE;
drop table if exists PILOT;
drop table if exists ASSIGNED_TO;
drop table if exists AIRCRAFT;
drop table if exists DEPARTURE;
drop table if exists FLIGHT;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Street VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
State VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Zip_Code INT NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (Name) );

CREATE TABLE BOOKED_ON(
Customer_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Departure_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Flight_num INT,
PRIMARY KEY (Flight_num),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_name) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(Name));

CREATE TABLE PLANE_TYPE(
Model_no VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Manufacturer VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Unique(Model_no),
PRIMARY KEY (Model_no, Manufacturer) );

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
employee_no INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Salary INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (employee_no));

CREATE TABLE PILOT(
Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
License_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Plane_model_can_fly VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (License_Date),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employee_no));

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNED_TO(
Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
dep_date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
flight_num INT,
PRIMARY KEY (Employee_no),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employee_no),
FOREIGN KEY (flight_num) REFERENCES BOOKED_ON(Flight_num)
 );

CREATE TABLE AIRCRAFT(
Serial_no VARCHAR(50) ,
Model_no VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (Serial_no),
FOREIGN KEY (Model_no) REFERENCES PLANE_TYPE(Model_no)

);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTURE(
Departure_date DATE NOT NULL,
Flight_number INT,
Aircraft_Serial_no VARCHAR(50) ,
Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Flight_number),
FOREIGN KEY (Flight_number) REFERENCES BOOKED_ON (Flight_num),
FOREIGN KEY (employee_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Employee_no),
FOREIGN KEY (Aircraft_Serial_no) REFERENCES AIRCRAFT(Serial_no));
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT(
flight_num INT,
origin VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
dest VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
dep_time VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
arr_time VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(flight_num),
FOREIGN KEY (flight_num) REFERENCES BOOKED_ON (Flight_num)
);
 /*Populate Customer table*/

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES
('Rose', 'Parker', '123 Thomas St', 'Toledo', 'OH', 57556, '801-556-2239'),
('Jessica', 'Jones', '234 Pines St', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', 34898, '801-552-2943'),
('John', 'Peters', '345 Star St', 'Raleigh', 'NC', 79999, '801-393-2230'),
('Bryan', 'Brown', '435 Palm St', 'Miami', 'FL', 30533, '801-933-2320'),
('Mark', 'Williams', '348 Andrew St', 'Fort Lauderdale', 'FL', 33318, '801-343-2320'),
('Carol', 'Phillips', '395 Pine St', 'Omaha', 'NE', 88899, '801-323-2320'),
('Madison', 'Parker', '285 Diamond St', 'San Diego', 'CA', 99977, '801-493-2203'),
('Justin', 'Colano', '223 Easy St', 'Tampa', 'FL', 66798, '801-193-2320'),
('Claudia', 'Stevens', '775 Main St', 'Saint Louis', 'MO', 99878, '801-303-2222'),
('Arthur', 'Hooper', '456 Rose St', 'Las Vegas', 'NV', 17878, '313-912-2101'),
('Sergio', 'Ryan', '567 Spruce St', 'Lincoln', 'NE', 87898, '801-228-6729'),
('Julia', 'Maverick', '678 Tulip St', 'Raleigh', 'NC', 79999, NULL),
('Brandon', 'Gordon', '789 First St', 'Miami', 'FL', 30533, NULL);



/*Populate PLANE_TYPE table*/

INSERT INTO PLANE_TYPE VALUES
('B727', 'Boeing'),
('B747', 'Boeing'),
('B757', 'Boeing'),
('DC9', 'MD'),
('DC10', 'MD'),
('A310', 'Airbus'),
('A320', 'Airbus'),
('A330', 'Airbus'),
('DA340', 'Airbus');

/*Populate EMPLOYEE table*/

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
(1001,'John Jones', 90000),
(1002,'Albert Peters',85000),
(1003,'Carl Rowe',115000),
(1004,'Phillips', 25000),
(1005,'William Gates', 50000),
(1006,'Robert Clark', 45000),
(1007,'Joseph Warnock', 50000),
(1008,'Lisa Stuart',75000);

/*Populate FLIGHT table*/

INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES
(100, 'SLC', 'BOS', '8:00', '17:50'),
(206, 'DFW', 'STL', '9:00', '11:40'),
(334, 'ORD', 'MIA', '12:00', '14:14'),
(335, 'MIA', 'ORD', '15:00', '17:14'),
(336, 'ORD', 'MIA', '18:00', '20:14'),
(337, 'MIA', 'ORD', '20:30', '23:53'),
(121, 'STL', 'SLC', '7:00', '9:13'),
(122, 'JFK', 'YYV', '16:00', '18:53'),
(330, 'STL', 'YYV', '8:30', '10:19'),
(991, 'BOS', 'ORD', '17:00', '18:22'),
(394, 'DFW', 'MIA', '19:00', '21:30'),
(395, 'MIA', 'DFW', '21:00', '23:43'),
(449, 'CDG', 'DEN', '10:00', '19:29'),
(930, 'YYV', 'DCA', '13:00', '16:10'),
(931, 'DCA', 'YYV', '17:00', '18:10'),
(932, 'DCA', 'YYV', '18:00', '19:10'),
(112, 'DCA', 'DEN', '14:00', '18:07');



/*Populate Pilot table*/

INSERT INTO PILOT VALUES
(1001, 'John Jones', '06/01/1999', 'B727'),
(1001, 'John Jones', '08/14/2000', 'B747'),
(1001, 'John Jones', '04/20/2005', 'DC10'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '09/25/2010', 'DC9'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '04/20/2005', 'A310'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '07/17/2003', 'B757'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '05/2/2012', 'A320'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '12/01/2015', 'B727'),
(1003, 'Carol Rowe', '01/25/2013', 'A310'),
(1003, 'Carol Rowe', '06/05/2015', 'DC9');


/*Populate Booked_on table*/

INSERT INTO BOOKED_ON VALUES
('Rose Parker','10/31/2018', 100),
('Bryan Brown','10/31/2018', 206),
('Arthur Hooper','10/31/2018', 334),
('Sergio Ryan','10/31/2018', 449),
('Brandon Gardon','11/01/2018', 991),
('Madison Parker','11/01/2018', 991),
('Mark Williams', '11/01/2018', 100),
('Carol Phillips', '11/01/2018', 100),
('Justin Colano','10/31/2018', 449),
('Claudia Stevens','10/31/2018', 449),
('Julia Maverick','11/01/2018', 991),
('John Peters','11/01/2018', 100);

/*Populate AirCraft table*/

INSERT INTO AIRCRAFT VALUES
('B1110', 'B727'),
('B1325', 'B727'),
('B1088', 'B747'),
('B1419', 'B747'),
('B2244', 'B757'),
('B9377', 'B757'),
('D2101', 'DC9'),
('D2216', 'DC9'),
('D2333', 'DC9'),
('D2429', 'DC9'),
('D2530', 'DC10'),
('A7099', 'A310'),
('A8055', 'A320');

/*Populate DEPARTURE table*/

INSERT INTO DEPARTURE VALUES
('10/31/2018', 100, 'B1110'),
('10/31/2018', 112, NULL),
('10/31/2018', 206, 'D2530'),
('10/31/2018', 334, NULL),
('10/31/2018', 335, NULL),
('10/31/2018', 337, ‘D2216’),
('10/31/2018', 449, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 100, 'D2530'),
('11/1/2018', 112, 'A8055'),
('11/1/2018', 206, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 334, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 395, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 991, 'B1325');

INSERT INTO ASSIGNED_TO VALUES
(1001, '10/31/2018', 100),
(1003, '10/31/2018', 100),
(1004, '10/31/2018', 100),
(1002, '10/31/2018', 206),
(1003, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1004, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1005, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1006, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1001, '11/1/2018', 100),
(1005, '11/1/2018', 100),
(1007, '11/1/2018', 100),
(1003, '11/1/2018', 991),
(1006, '11/1/2018', 991),
(1007, '11/1/2018', 991),
(1002, '11/1/2018', 112),
(1004, '11/1/2018', 112),
(1008, '11/1/2018', 112);
```

Values will not update due to foreign key and duplicate keys. I attempted to change the create table code. I am unsure if I have to add constraints or change the create table code. Please assist with the code

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you everything? Insert the rows to `booked_on` first.

Comment: I have inserted the rows to booked_on. That is why I do not know what the issue is.

Comment: You need to add rows to `booked_on` before you can add any to `flight`.

Answer (score 0):

You insert flight before booke_on, need use go for order of insert.

See new query:

```
drop table if exists CUSTOMER;
drop table if exists BOOKED_ON;
drop table if exists PLANE_TYPE;
drop table if exists EMPLOYEE;
drop table if exists PILOT;
drop table if exists ASSIGNED_TO;
drop table if exists AIRCRAFT;
drop table if exists DEPARTURE;
drop table if exists FLIGHT;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Street VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
City VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
State VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Zip_Code INT NOT NULL,
Phone VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (Name) );

CREATE TABLE BOOKED_ON(
Customer_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Departure_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Flight_num INT,
PRIMARY KEY (Flight_num),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_name) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(Name));

CREATE TABLE PLANE_TYPE(
Model_no VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Manufacturer VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Unique(Model_no),
PRIMARY KEY (Model_no, Manufacturer) );

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
employee_no INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Salary INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (employee_no));

CREATE TABLE PILOT(
Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
License_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Plane_model_can_fly VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (License_Date),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employee_no));

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNED_TO(
Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
dep_date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
flight_num INT,
PRIMARY KEY (Employee_no),
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employee_no),
FOREIGN KEY (flight_num) REFERENCES BOOKED_ON(Flight_num)
 );

CREATE TABLE AIRCRAFT(
Serial_no VARCHAR(50) ,
Model_no VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (Serial_no),
FOREIGN KEY (Model_no) REFERENCES PLANE_TYPE(Model_no)

);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTURE(
Departure_date DATE NOT NULL,
Flight_number INT,
Aircraft_Serial_no VARCHAR(50) ,
Employee_no INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Flight_number),
FOREIGN KEY (Flight_number) REFERENCES BOOKED_ON (Flight_num),
FOREIGN KEY (employee_no) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Employee_no),
FOREIGN KEY (Aircraft_Serial_no) REFERENCES AIRCRAFT(Serial_no));

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT(
flight_num INT,
origin VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
dest VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
dep_time VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
arr_time VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(flight_num),
FOREIGN KEY (flight_num) REFERENCES BOOKED_ON (Flight_num)
);
 /*Populate Customer table*/

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES
('Rose', 'Parker', '123 Thomas St', 'Toledo', 'OH', 57556, '801-556-2239'),
('Jessica', 'Jones', '234 Pines St', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', 34898, '801-552-2943'),
('John', 'Peters', '345 Star St', 'Raleigh', 'NC', 79999, '801-393-2230'),
('Bryan', 'Brown', '435 Palm St', 'Miami', 'FL', 30533, '801-933-2320'),
('Mark', 'Williams', '348 Andrew St', 'Fort Lauderdale', 'FL', 33318, '801-343-2320'),
('Carol', 'Phillips', '395 Pine St', 'Omaha', 'NE', 88899, '801-323-2320'),
('Madison', 'Parker', '285 Diamond St', 'San Diego', 'CA', 99977, '801-493-2203'),
('Justin', 'Colano', '223 Easy St', 'Tampa', 'FL', 66798, '801-193-2320'),
('Claudia', 'Stevens', '775 Main St', 'Saint Louis', 'MO', 99878, '801-303-2222'),
('Arthur', 'Hooper', '456 Rose St', 'Las Vegas', 'NV', 17878, '313-912-2101'),
('Sergio', 'Ryan', '567 Spruce St', 'Lincoln', 'NE', 87898, '801-228-6729'),
('Julia', 'Maverick', '678 Tulip St', 'Raleigh', 'NC', 79999, NULL),
('Brandon', 'Gordon', '789 First St', 'Miami', 'FL', 30533, NULL);



/*Populate PLANE_TYPE table*/

INSERT INTO PLANE_TYPE VALUES
('B727', 'Boeing'),
('B747', 'Boeing'),
('B757', 'Boeing'),
('DC9', 'MD'),
('DC10', 'MD'),
('A310', 'Airbus'),
('A320', 'Airbus'),
('A330', 'Airbus'),
('DA340', 'Airbus');

/*Populate EMPLOYEE table*/

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
(1001,'John Jones', 90000),
(1002,'Albert Peters',85000),
(1003,'Carl Rowe',115000),
(1004,'Phillips', 25000),
(1005,'William Gates', 50000),
(1006,'Robert Clark', 45000),
(1007,'Joseph Warnock', 50000),
(1008,'Lisa Stuart',75000);





/*Populate Pilot table*/

INSERT INTO PILOT VALUES
(1001, 'John Jones', '06/01/1999', 'B727'),
(1001, 'John Jones', '08/14/2000', 'B747'),
(1001, 'John Jones', '04/20/2005', 'DC10'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '09/25/2010', 'DC9'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '04/20/2005', 'A310'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '07/17/2003', 'B757'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '05/2/2012', 'A320'),
(1002, 'Albert Peters', '12/01/2015', 'B727'),
(1003, 'Carol Rowe', '01/25/2013', 'A310'),
(1003, 'Carol Rowe', '06/05/2015', 'DC9');

/*before inser booked_ontable*/
GO
/*Populate Booked_on table*/

INSERT INTO BOOKED_ON VALUES
('Rose Parker','10/31/2018', 100),
('Bryan Brown','10/31/2018', 206),
('Arthur Hooper','10/31/2018', 334),
('Sergio Ryan','10/31/2018', 449),
('Brandon Gardon','11/01/2018', 991),
('Madison Parker','11/01/2018', 991),
('Mark Williams', '11/01/2018', 100),
('Carol Phillips', '11/01/2018', 100),
('Justin Colano','10/31/2018', 449),
('Claudia Stevens','10/31/2018', 449),
('Julia Maverick','11/01/2018', 991),
('John Peters','11/01/2018', 100);

/* after insert flight*/
GO
/*Populate FLIGHT table*/

INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES
(100, 'SLC', 'BOS', '8:00', '17:50'),
(206, 'DFW', 'STL', '9:00', '11:40'),
(334, 'ORD', 'MIA', '12:00', '14:14'),
(335, 'MIA', 'ORD', '15:00', '17:14'),
(336, 'ORD', 'MIA', '18:00', '20:14'),
(337, 'MIA', 'ORD', '20:30', '23:53'),
(121, 'STL', 'SLC', '7:00', '9:13'),
(122, 'JFK', 'YYV', '16:00', '18:53'),
(330, 'STL', 'YYV', '8:30', '10:19'),
(991, 'BOS', 'ORD', '17:00', '18:22'),
(394, 'DFW', 'MIA', '19:00', '21:30'),
(395, 'MIA', 'DFW', '21:00', '23:43'),
(449, 'CDG', 'DEN', '10:00', '19:29'),
(930, 'YYV', 'DCA', '13:00', '16:10'),
(931, 'DCA', 'YYV', '17:00', '18:10'),
(932, 'DCA', 'YYV', '18:00', '19:10'),
(112, 'DCA', 'DEN', '14:00', '18:07');
/*Populate AirCraft table*/

INSERT INTO AIRCRAFT VALUES
('B1110', 'B727'),
('B1325', 'B727'),
('B1088', 'B747'),
('B1419', 'B747'),
('B2244', 'B757'),
('B9377', 'B757'),
('D2101', 'DC9'),
('D2216', 'DC9'),
('D2333', 'DC9'),
('D2429', 'DC9'),
('D2530', 'DC10'),
('A7099', 'A310'),
('A8055', 'A320');

/*Populate DEPARTURE table*/

INSERT INTO DEPARTURE VALUES
('10/31/2018', 100, 'B1110'),
('10/31/2018', 112, NULL),
('10/31/2018', 206, 'D2530'),
('10/31/2018', 334, NULL),
('10/31/2018', 335, NULL),
('10/31/2018', 337, ‘D2216’),
('10/31/2018', 449, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 100, 'D2530'),
('11/1/2018', 112, 'A8055'),
('11/1/2018', 206, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 334, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 395, NULL),
('11/1/2018', 991, 'B1325');

INSERT INTO ASSIGNED_TO VALUES
(1001, '10/31/2018', 100),
(1003, '10/31/2018', 100),
(1004, '10/31/2018', 100),
(1002, '10/31/2018', 206),
(1003, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1004, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1005, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1006, '10/31/2018', 337),
(1001, '11/1/2018', 100),
(1005, '11/1/2018', 100),
(1007, '11/1/2018', 100),
(1003, '11/1/2018', 991),
(1006, '11/1/2018', 991),
(1007, '11/1/2018', 991),
(1002, '11/1/2018', 112),
(1004, '11/1/2018', 112),
(1008, '11/1/2018', 112);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something further to add.

In your `BOOKED_ON` create you specify that `flight_num` is your primary key

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKED_ON(
Customer_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Departure_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Flight_num INT,
PRIMARY KEY (Flight_num),
FOREIGN KEY (Customer_name) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(Name));
```

However, in your data you are not entering unique values for flight number into that table. e.g.

```
('Brandon Gardon','11/01/2018', 991),
('Madison Parker','11/01/2018', 991),
```

There are a number of confusing relationships in your model, you might want to give the design phase another once over.